# Detecting a cancelled drag and drop action when uploading files

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

This is the behavior I want:

1. The user starts dragging a file from the file explorer
2. When the file hovers over the browser window 3 drop zones appear
3. When the user cancels the drag and drop or drops the file the drop zones disappear.

The problem I'm having is with #3.
The drop zones appear fine when using the `dragenter` on `document` but I can't get them to disappear again.

I've tried binding on `dragend` which never fires, `dragleave` which fires every time the the drag leaves a descendant so the drag area blinks.

Which event would be the correct one to listen to?

Answer (score 9):

I haven't fully tested it, but it seems as though you could leverage the annoying behaviour of `dragenter` and `dragleave` which fires on every single element.

```
var counter = 0;
$(document).on('dragenter', function () { 
  if (counter++ === 0) {
    console.log('entered the page');
  }
});

$(document).on('dragleave', function () {
  if (--counter === 0) {
    console.log('left the page');
  }
});
```

Seems to also work if the drag is cancelled by pressing escape.

http://jsbin.com/atodem/2/

Comment: Don't forget to add on dragover to prevent default drag&drop, besides works exactly as I want it to!

Comment: Be careful, because this breaks easily. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ueLfnLz6/3/) that shows only one of the problems. Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29869208/636561) for an alternative.

Comment: Works like a charm on Chrome and Firefox, but the counter sometimes goes wrong  on IE 11.

Answer (score 7):

On `document`, you want to listen to both `dragleave` and `dragover`, to hide and show the zones respectively.

Comment: The problem is that I want to fade the dropzones in and that causes bugs when moving the file around (the dropzones flicker). I'm guessing this is due to the propagation of the events.

Comment: It works if I don't hide/show the drop zones using `display: none` but that way the user can still interact with them wich is bad.

Comment: What causes the flicker, the dragleave?

Comment: Yeah, the dragleave bubbles up to the document sadly.

Comment: I solved this by working around the problem instead but thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `dragstart` and `dragend` events appear to only fire when dragging something *from* the browser *to* the browser, which is hardly useful in your case.  I couldn't seem to stop the flicker, but if you add a timeout to the `dragenter` and `dragleave` events, you can minimize the flicker:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var drag = new (function(){
        var timeout;
        this.detected = function(){
            return !(timeout === undefined)
        }
        this.start = function(){
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        function endDrag(){
            for (var i=0;i<3;i++) //no longer dragging, remove drop zones
                document.getElementsByClassName("dropZone")[i].style.display="none";
        }
        this.end = function(){
            timeout = setTimeout((function(){timeout=undefined;endDrag();}),1500)
        }
    })()
    document.body.ondragenter = function(){
        drag.start();
        for (var i=0;i<3;i++) //drag started, show drop zones
            document.getElementsByClassName("dropZone")[i].style.display="block";
    }
    document.body.ondragleave = function(event){
        event = event||window.event
        if ((event.source||event.target)==document.body)
            drag.end();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, sorry if it isn't perfect.  :-(

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answered worked for me. For my case, I needed to raise the drop-target z-index above other elements when dragging started, and lower it back after dragging ended. What I found was that when dragging was initiated, the `mousemove` event stopped firing. I used that behavior to detect when the drag actually stopped.

#### NOTE: only tested w/ firefox v104

```
let dragging = false;

function dragInit(event) {
    // add drag-init class to all drop targets, raising their z-index 
    if (dragging) return // prevent duplicate calls
    dragging = true
    for (const dt of document.querySelectorAll('.droptarget')) dt.classList.add('drag-init')
    // bind mousemove to body element; mouse move events are stopped while dragging 
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', dragEnd)
}

function dragEnd(event) {
    // when the dragging ends, the mousemove events are generated, remove the drag-init class to lower the 
    // droptargets back below the other elements 
    dragging = false
    // remove the listener, no longer needed
    document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragEnd)
    for (const dt of document.querySelectorAll('.droptarget')) dt.classList.remove('drag-init')
}
// initialize drag and drop
document.body.addEventListener('dragenter', dragInit)
```

### CSS

```
.droptarget {
    // start the drop target below other elements
    z-index: -1;
}

.droptarget.drag-init {
// user is currently dragging, raise the drop target above other elements 
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Is this standard behavior or just for some specific browser that works for now?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify it by checking if drop has been called before dragend.

```
     var dragConfirmed;

     document.addEventListener("drop", function( event ) {
          // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
          event.preventDefault();

          dragConfirmed = true;
      }, false);



      document.addEventListener("dragend", function( event ) {

        if (dragConfirmed != true)
        {
             // Escape has been pressed
        }

      }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

dragleave didn't work for me. I used a timeout:

```
function stopDrag(){
   console.log('bye drag!');
}

var timeoutHandle;
document.addEventListener('dragover', function(){
    console.log('you are dragging');
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(stopDrag, 200);
}, false);
```