# HTML5 drag and drop not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I've made an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NQQL6/

When I start dragging a link, the cart should turn to green. When the item is dragged over the cart, the cart should become red.

This works, but only if the cart is empty :|

If there are any other elements in it, `leave` seems to be triggered when I drag the item over those elements. How can I prevent that from happening?

I've tried moving the event listener to the `document` element and check if `event.target` is a child or grandchild of `cart` but then `leave` seems to be triggered randomly on `body` even when the item is within the cart zone, so my class gets removed when it's not supposed to :(

Edit: found a few hacky solutions here:
['dragleave' of parent element fires when dragging over children elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867506/dragleave-of-parent-element-fires-when-dragging-over-children-elements)

so you can delete this Q :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the following css to the list:

```
ul{ pointer-events: none; }
```

See this updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NQQL6/1/

EDIT:
Try this, http://jsfiddle.net/NQQL6/6/

Slightly more js logic, but it should work now.

Comment: links within the cart become unclickable if I do that

Comment: `ul * { pointer-events: all; }` to re-enable pointer events for all child elements within the `ul`

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the game, you probably solved this, but you need to keep a reference counter to count the dragleave/dragenter events :

```
var counter = 0;

cart.addEventListener('dragenter', function(event){  
    counter++;
    cart.classList.add('ontop', 'activate');
    console.log('enter');
});

cart.addEventListener('dragleave', function(event){
  counter--;
  if (counter === 0) {
    cart.classList.remove('ontop');
  }
  console.log('leave');
});
```

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/NQQL6/9/)

See also this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110353/html5-dragleave-fired-when-hovering-a-child-element/21002544#21002544).