# Ink Filepicker makeDropPane on html/body, dragLeave fired immediately after dragEnter

Tags: filepicker.io

I am trying to attach a Ink Filepicker handler on the whole viewport, so that the user can drop files everywhere in the page. Here is the code i've been trying so far:

```coffeescript
window.filepicker.makeDropPane $("html")[0], # or $("body")[0]  
  mimetype: "image/*"
  multiple: true
  dragEnter: -> console.log "dragenter fired"
  dragLeave: -> console.log "dragleave fired"
  onSuccess: (files) -> # do stuff
  onError: (type, message) => # do other stuff
  onProgress: (percent) -> # do other stuff
```

Every time I drag the files in the browser, the dragLeave is fired immediately after the dragEnter, making impossible for me to do stuff.
Furthermore, if I put a div on top of everything to which I create the Filepicker pane, I obviously cannot interact with the page content anymore, unless I recognize the dragenter event independently by the one triggered by Filepicker so that i can change the z-index on-the-fly.

Let me know if i am not clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This solved this issue for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10867618/2698282

Comment: so how did you end up fixing this?