# AngularJS drag and drop twitches

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, angularjs-directive

I learn AngularJS Drag and Drop.
My code is working correctly. I move between each other DIV.

```
app.directive('draggable', function() 
app.directive('droppable', function()
```

But when the DIV contains elements that animation is choppy.
You can try it myself as an example:

[Sample plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xKgJAIzMjy1puL8AsNkz?p=preview)

How can I get around this problem?
Thx.

Upd.
Works poorly only in chrome. In firefox everything is acceptable

Upd2.
I found it Issue:
[Bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131325)

Comment: your plnkr link is broken. Can you update?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/xKgJAIzMjy1puL8AsNkz?p=preview sorry

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867506/dragleave-of-parent-element-fires-when-dragging-over-children-elements) answer

```
  .child-elements {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```