# js addeventlistener use capture for dragenter not working for input elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a event listener for `dragenter` on a container div holding input items. But it only works on the parent div, if you hover over the inputs the `dragleave` event is triggered. Should capture not mean that the inputs are triggering the parent event?

The event listeners are added below.

```
addDragStartListen: function(){
        var fields = document.querySelectorAll('.formFieldType');
        [].forEach.call(fields, function(field) {
            field.addEventListener('dragstart', FORMBUILD.DragStart, true);
        });

        var DItems = document.querySelectorAll('.f-row');
        [].forEach.call(DItems, function(DItem) {
            DItem.addEventListener('dragenter', FORMBUILD.DragEnter, false);
            DItem.addEventListener('dragover', FORMBUILD.DragOver, true);
            DItem.addEventListener('dragleave', FORMBUILD.DragLeave, false);
            DItem.addEventListener('drop', FORMBUILD.DragDrop, false);
        });



    },
```

See here for a codepen showing the issue when you drag the element over the inputs, `dragleave` is triggered. http://codepen.io/ambrosedheffernan/pen/PPqdMd

note: the code in codepen has remove listener on dragenter and addlistener on dragleave.

I am testing in chrome which should support capture but why can i not do this for inputs? is there another event that is taking precedence by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture means that events will be triggered from parent to child.
In your case I think when you drag item to container and then to its child input, `dragenter` and `dragleave` gets triggered for container and `dragenter` triggered for input.

As an idea, you can create a variable that would hold actual drag entered/leaved state, i.e. when `dragenter` and `dragleave` happened same amount of times, then consider dragged element to be out of container.

Comment: thanks mate, I think i get what you are saying, each child element is starting a new event?

Comment: right, it will be triggered for each child, there is similar topic discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867506/dragleave-of-parent-element-fires-when-dragging-over-children-elements) and it has several answers that might be helpful to you